# Converse of a proposition on BE-algebras

Tags: universal-algebra

A BE-algebra $(B,*,1)$ is a type $<2,0>$ algebra satisfying the identities:

1. $x*x=1$

2.$x*1=1$

3.$1*x=x$

4.$x*(y*z)=y*(x*z)$.

Define a relation $R(x,y)$ that holds iff $x*y=1$. It can be proven that $R$ is a partial order if the identity $(x*y)*y=(y*x)*x$ holds.

My question is whether the converse is true.

That is to say, if $R$ is a partial order, does the identity $(x*y)*y=(y*x)*x$ hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The converse is not true in general.
Please see Example 3.8 (ii)[1].
[1] S. S. Ahn, Y. H. Kim and J. M. Ko, Filters in commutative BE-algebras, Commun. Korean Math. Soc. 27(2012), No. 2, pp. 233-242.

Best regards
Akbar Rezaei
Department of Mathematics,
Payame Noor University,
Tehran, Iran.
Email: rezaei.pnuk@gmail.com

Here is that example:

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\ast & 1 & a & b & 0 \\
\hline 
1 & 1 & a & b & 0 \\
a & 1 & 1 & b & 0 \\
b & 1 & a & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}

We have $(a\ast0)\ast0=0\ast0=1\neq a=1\ast a=(0\ast a)\ast a$, so that the identity is not satisfied. However, the order defined by $R$ is a diamond lattice with top $1$, bottom $0$, and atoms $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hopefully the downvoter can reconsider now that example is explicitly given.